# Propagating Node.js stream error events to async await style code

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-stream

I use readable and transform streams which I later consume using `for await`.

I cannot find a way to process callee's stream errors so they can be caught in the caller function.

For example if `transform` throws, it results in uncaught error.

If I add on error listener to `transform`, naturally it doesn't propagate the error to main's catch.

```
function handler(err) {
  // Log the error here
  // If throw from here it won't be cauch in main
  // How do I propagate it to main?
}

function getStream() {
  // transform1 and transform2 are custom transform streams
  readable.pipe(csvParser).pipe(transform1).pipe(transform2);
  readable.on('error', handler);
  csvParser.on('error', handler);
  transform1.on('error', handler);
  transform2.on('error', handler);
  return transform2;
}

async function main() {
  try {
    const stream = getStream();
    for await(const chunk of stream) {
      // process chunk
    }
  } catch (ex) {
    // how to catch transform errors here?
  }
}
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Where are you getting `transform` from in the `getStream` function?

Comment: @h-sifat my own custom written transform stream

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this with `Promise.race`:

```js
function readStream(stream) {
  return Promise.race([
    new Promise((_, reject) => stream.once('error', reject)),
    iterate(stream)
  ]);
}

async function iterate(stream) {
  for await (const object of stream) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This will reject with any error from either the stream or the `iterate` function, or resolve with the result of `iterate`, whichever comes first.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it async/await is largely syntactic sugar on top of promises. Specifically I think that since ReadableStream.pipe follows an event-based (`on("error", errorHandler)`) rather than promise-based pattern, the `try { ... await ... } catch (ex) { ... }` construction isn't going to handle asynchronous errors "thrown" within ReadableStream.pipe as seamlessly as you might hope.

Assuming my understanding is correct (and to be honest I don't use the aysnc/await syntax often, so it's possible I'm missing something too) one straightforward work-around is to fall back to adding a callback-based event handler like this:

```
function handleError(err) { ... }

readable.once("error", handleError);

// and if you want, re-use that handler within your catch block, like:
// `} catch (ex) { handleError(ex); }`
// but I'm not sure how often that will come up if you follow this pattern
```

but you may already be aware of that.

Failing that, if you really want to use the aysnc/await/try/catch-style construction in this case you could use something like `util.promisify` to convert the `on("error", handler)`-event-based API that ReadableStream is using to promises. This StackOverflow post - [How to use Async await using util promisify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57688097/how-to-use-async-await-using-util-promisify) - covers that topic in more depth but (IMO) that seems like a lot of hoops to jump through just to avoid adding `readable.once("error" /* ...whatever you'd otherwise have in your catch block ... */)`

In short, I think because ReadableStream.pipe isn't designed around promises, the async/await syntax isn't enough (in and of itself) to ensure that the asynchronous errors that might be emitted as on-error events are trapped by the try/catch block. You need to handle those errors in the old-school way, either directly (by registering a handler for the error events emitted by your `readable`, in which case the await and try/catch stuff isn't directly applicable)  or "indirectly" (by creating an adapter that makes those emitted-events bubble up like the catch case on a resolved promise, in which case you can make it look like a synchronous-style try/catch using async/await).

Comment: That's all correct, but assuming at the high level for the error to be displayed to the user it needs to be thrown, I can *log* the error by adding an *error* listener, but I cannot throw it and display to the user.  That's my problem.

Comment: Well again I'm pretty sure you could wrap the error handler using promisify to allow the async/await/try/catch keywords to work as implied in your original post (as described in the SO link above) Or alternatively, if if your onError handler was something like `function onError(err) { throw err; }` wouldn't that be sufficient to get the error to bubble-up to the general-purpose "unhandled exception" handler? More generally if you're not relying on the default unhandled case you could call whatever reporting mechanism is used from the onError handler just like you do from the catch block.

Comment: No, it's not sufficient.  Error thrown in `onError` handler won't buble up to main.  I could wrap the whole `getStream` into a promise, but I cannot await on it.  Because then execution would stall.  I need to start executing `for await` loop to trigger an error in transform.  That means I cannot await on a promise returned by `getStream`, because it will never resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I think a transform stream function should not throw an exception. Instead it should emit an error event or pass the error to the call back function.

Here is an example.

#### Edit

Wrap everything in the transform method with a try catch block. And it propagates to the main function.

```js
const { Transform } = require("stream");

//Added on 1st edit
function handler(ex) {
  console.error("Logged By Handler: ", ex);
}

function getStream() {
  // A simple transform stream to test
  const transform = new Transform({
    transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
      try {
        chunk = chunk.toString();

        // if chunk == "err" then we want to throw an error
        // to simulate a real life error
        if (chunk === "err\n") 
        return callback("Oops! Sth failed in the transform stream.", null);
        // or this.emit("error", "Oops! Sth failed in the transform stream.");

        this.push(chunk.toUpperCase());

        // Simulating exception
        throw new Error(`Fatal error.`);
        callback();
      } catch (ex) {
        handler(ex);
        callback(ex, null);
      }
    },
  });

  process.stdin.pipe(transform);
  // readable    ->   transform
  return transform;
}

async function main(transform) {
  try {
    for await (const chunk of transform) process.stdout.write(chunk);
  } catch (ex) {
    console.error("Handled by main:", ex);
  }
}

main(getStream());
```

Comment: If there is an error in transform, it will be emited as `error` event on transform.  This doesn't solve my problem of catching it in main.  I can add `error` event listener, but I cannot propagate an error from there to main error handler.

An error can also be emitted in the same manner from `csvParser` stream.  I can also added an `error` listenere.  But I also *cannot* catch it in main error handler.

Comment: What do you mean by `I also cannot catch it in main error handler`? In my code, in the main function it catches the error. But the stack trace is missing though and I don't know why!

Comment: Oh wait you updated your code! Lemme check

Comment: Hey @krl I've followed your code pattern and added an error handler like you. But it still propagates to the main function!

Comment: if I throw inside ANY `on('error')`, Node.js crashes cause it ends up being unhandled.

Comment: In your example, add `const sdf = sdfdf.df;` after `chunk = chunk.toString();`, run it and see that it crashes Node.js, the error is NOT caught in main's catch.

Comment: @krl now it works. Though I think it's a nasty solution. You better read the docs to find more elegant solution.

Comment: I can confirm your code is working.  Mine, while much more complex, is the same in principle, but it's not working :(  Node crashes due to no `error` event listener on transform.